# jQuery nice scroll won't let me scroll the page when I'm done scrolling an overflow: auto element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nicescroll

I'm using jQuery nice scroll plugin on my whole document, and an element inside my document that has an overflow property of auto.

When that element overflows, scroll-bars appear, but when I'm done scrolling that element, I have to move my cursor out of that element for the document to start scrolling.

Without nice scroll plugin, after scrolling that element, I didn't have to move my mouse out for the document to keep scrolling again. It would scroll after that element.

I want to have my nice scroll plugin, and I want this problem fixed. Any suggestions?

Check out this fiddle without nice scrolls:
http://jsfiddle.net/vahidseo/5mrmp/

Here are the styles I gave to the div:

```
#scroll {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

That's the effect I want. If you scroll the small div, when the scroll-bar reaches the bottom, as soon as you scroll again, the page scroll.

Comment: can you produce a http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Sure. Here it is, without nice scroll: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/vahidseo/5mrmp/)
As you can see, when you're mouse is in the small div, when the scroll-bar reaches the bottom, the page scrolls. That doesn't happen when I have nice scroll.

Comment: @vahidseo: Good of you to create the fiddle. Always put the relevant code and markup **in** the question, don't just link (not even to jsFiddle). Separately: To improve or add to the question, use the "edit" link, not comments.

Comment: I am not trying to criticize you but your question is badly phrased which in effect makes it difficult to understand be specific about what you want